Could I use a linkstyle momentary dpdt switch?

This is a switch from my cars sunroof. It is a Lincoln Town Car so the part is Ford.
I need to replace this switch and I am wondering if I can just get a linkstyle dpdt switch and solder these four wires to the four posts on the switch. If not I will just have to de solder the PCB I guess. Just not my area of expertise. Thanks

You either need the PCB or at least wire the switch correctly the way the PCB does.
Look at the copper wiring on PCB.
The RED wire is switched between the BLUE and BLACK(?) wires.
When RED and BLUE are connected together, so are two other wires connected together, YELLOW and BLACK(?).
When RED wire is connected to BLACK(?) then BLUE is disconnected from RED and YELLOW is disconnected from BLACK(?).
Do verify the above with a multimeter so you don't damage anything.

What do you mean by its switched? Sorry again I am trying to learn more electrical engineering but I really only do software. So you're saying that when the switch is closed in a certain direction (Also yes it is black) the circuit is closed?
